# Popup displays div just on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am using the [jQuery Simple Slider Plugin](https://github.com/amitsankhe/Jquery-SimpleSlider) to display extra information for images, when they are clicked on by the user.
This plugin displays an image description in the popup window. That works fine.

---

### THE PROBLEM

However, **I would like to add another div to the popup**, with the class name 'like-image'.
**The first time you click the image everything works as I would like it to.** The image description and the like-image div are both displayed.
**If you click the image another time** without reloading the page before, the **like-image div is not displayed anymore**.
**What am I doing wrong?**

---

### [THE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljf0wmj3/7/)

---

### HTML

```
<ul  class="product-gallery">
    <li class="gallery-img">
        <img src='http://lorempixel.com/200/300' alt="img01" /> 
        <div class="image-description" data-desc="Image1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy"></div>
        <div class="like-image"><b>This div just displays on first click.</b></div>
    </li>                   
</ul>
```

### JQUERY

```
/*
* jQuery Slider Plugin
* Version : Am2_SimpleSlider.js
* author  :amit & amar
*/

(function ($) {

jQuery.fn.Am2_SimpleSlider = function () {
    //popup div
    $div = $('<div class="product-gallery-popup"> <div class="popup-overlay"></div><div class="product-popup-content"><div class="product-image"><img id="gallery-img" src="" alt="" /><div class="gallery-nav-btns"><a id="nav-btn-next" class="nav-btn next" ></a><a id="nav-btn-prev" class="nav-btn prev" ></a></div></div><div class="product-information"><p class="product-desc"></p><hr><div class="clear"></div><br><div class="like-image"></div><div class="clear"></div><hr></div><div class="clear"></div><a href="" class="cross">X</a></div></div>').appendTo('body');

    //on image click   
    $(this).click(function () {
        $('.product-gallery-popup').fadeIn(500);
        $('body').css({ 'overflow': 'hidden' });
        $('.product-popup-content .product-image img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
        $('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($(this).find('.image-description').attr('data-desc'));

        // My attempt of adding the div to the popup window
        // The next line of code seems just to work once
        $('.product-popup-content .product-information .like-image').html($(this).find('.like-image'));

        $Current = $(this);
        $PreviousElm = $(this).prev();
        $nextElm = $(this).next();
        if ($PreviousElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
        else { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
        if ($nextElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
        else { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
    });
    //on Next click
    $('.next').click(function () {
        $NewCurrent = $nextElm;
        $PreviousElm = $NewCurrent.prev();
        $nextElm = $NewCurrent.next();
        $('.product-popup-content .product-image img').clearQueue().animate({ opacity: '0' }, 0).attr('src', $NewCurrent.find('img').attr('src')).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 500);

        $('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($NewCurrent.find('.image-description').attr('data-desc'));
        $('.product-popup-content .product-information .like-image').html($NewCurrent.find('.like-image'));
        if ($PreviousElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
        else { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
        if ($nextElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
        else { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
    });
    //on Prev click
    $('.prev').click(function () {
        $NewCurrent = $PreviousElm;
        $PreviousElm = $NewCurrent.prev();
        $nextElm = $NewCurrent.next();
        $('.product-popup-content .product-image img').clearQueue().animate({ opacity: '0' }, 0).attr('src', $NewCurrent.find('img').attr('src')).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 500);

        $('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($NewCurrent.find('.image-description').attr('data-desc'));
        $('.product-popup-content .product-information .like-image').html($NewCurrent.find('.like-image'));
        if ($PreviousElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
        else { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
        if ($nextElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
        else { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
    });
    //Close Popup
    $('.cross,.popup-overlay').click(function () {
        $('.product-gallery-popup').fadeOut(500);
        $('body').css({ 'overflow': 'initial' });
    });

    //Key Events
    $(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Close popup on esc
        if (e.keyCode === 27) { $('.product-gallery-popup').fadeOut(500); $('body').css({ 'overflow': 'initial' }); }
        //Next Img On Right Arrow Click
        if (e.keyCode === 39) { NextProduct(); }
        //Prev Img on Left Arrow Click
        if (e.keyCode === 37) { PrevProduct(); }
    });

    function NextProduct() {
        if ($nextElm.length === 1) {
            $NewCurrent = $nextElm;
            $PreviousElm = $NewCurrent.prev();
            $nextElm = $NewCurrent.next();
            $('.product-popup-content .product-image img').clearQueue().animate({ opacity: '0' }, 0).attr('src', $NewCurrent.find('img').attr('src')).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 500);

            $('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($NewCurrent.find('.image-description').attr('data-desc'));
            $('.product-popup-content .product-information .like-image').html($NewCurrent.find('.like-image'));
            if ($PreviousElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
            else { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
            if ($nextElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
            else { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
        }

    }

    function PrevProduct() {
        if ($PreviousElm.length === 1) {
            $NewCurrent = $PreviousElm;
            $PreviousElm = $NewCurrent.prev();
            $nextElm = $NewCurrent.next();
            $('.product-popup-content .product-image img').clearQueue().animate({ opacity: '0' }, 0).attr('src', $NewCurrent.find('img').attr('src')).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 500);

            $('.product-popup-content .product-information p').text($NewCurrent.find('.image-description').attr('data-desc'));
            $('.product-popup-content .product-information .like-image').html($NewCurrent.find('.like-image'));
            if ($PreviousElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
            else { $('.nav-btn.prev').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
            if ($nextElm.length === 0) { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'none' }); }
            else { $('.nav-btn.next').css({ 'display': 'block' }); }
        }

    }
};

} (jQuery));

// Call the plugin
$('.gallery-img').Am2_SimpleSlider();
```

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your line with this one

```
   // My attempt of adding the div to the popup window
   // The next line of code seems just to work once
   $('.product-popup-content .product-information .like-image').html($(this).find('.like-image').html());
```

Let me know if you still find issues. I check it in the fiddle and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I cannot try out if it works until later today but if it works in the fiddle, I am sure it is going to work in my project! Thank you so so much for your help!!

Comment: Tried it out! Works like a charme! Thanks!